# Removing Header Titles from a UITableView in Search Mode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

Just noticed some undesired behavior in my UITableView, when it's in search mode. Here is a visual description of the issue, with my suspected method implementation at the bottom.

**(Step 1) The Complete List - OK!**

[image]

---

**(Step 2) Search Results - OK!**

[image]

---

**(Step 3) Drill Into a Search Result - OK!**

[image]

---

**(Step 4) Navigate Back to Search Results - Not OK! All Header indexes are being returned...**

[image]

---

Here is my method implementation that is returning all of the indices:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *sKeysArray = [[listContent allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    sorted = [sKeysArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:self.mySortBlock];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){

        return @"";

   } else {

    return [sorted objectAtIndex:section];
  }

}
```

What are best practices to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observed this behavior if `[self.tableView reloadData]` is called within `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

It seems that `reloadData` causes all section headers of the underlying table view to appear even if a search is active and  only the `searchResultsTableView` should be visible.

A solution could be to call `reloadData` only if `[self.searchDisplayController isActive] == NO`.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. You saved me a ton of time debugging this! That worked.